# What's the right syntax to use Rails `content_for` helper in a HAML context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

What are the differences in the use of `-` and `=` in the following:

```
- content_for :header do
  %h1 Title
```

and

```
= content_for :header do
  %h1 Title
```

What is the right way?

Comment: For those who's wondering, the difference is between the character `-` and `=`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That depends on what you want to do.

To render the header right away, do:

```
= content_for :header do
  %h1 Title
```

To store the content and use it later, do:

```
- content_for :header do
  %h1 Title
```

And to use it somewhere in your view(s):

```
= content_for :header
```

In Rails < 3.2 you needed to use `= yield :header`. That is still supported in Rails 3.2 but it doesn't work in helper modules while `content_for` does (thanks @drewish).

Comment: This changed in rails 3.2 right? Now you'd want to use `= content_for :header` instead of `= yield :header`?

Comment: Looks like you can still use both, but `yield` doesn't work in helper modules ([source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)).

Comment: Ah, I missed "do" in haml for content_for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`= yield :header`, although not deprecated, has been put to less use. Although Rails 3.2 supports this,  the problem occurs in helper modules.

`content_for`, on the other hand does work well and is a more often used command.