# Haml - operator forces rendering outside of div indentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

New to HAML, trying to get content into two columns, but the - operator seems to be rendering into the next div. Here's the code:

```
.col-md-5
  %label Sort by
  %p Sorting link
  - content_for :filter_exclude_words do
    .form-group
      = label_tag "exclude"
      = text_field_tag "exclude", params[:exclude], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Comma separated terms..."


.col-md-7
  ...
```

The resulting .form-group is being rendered in the next .col-md-7 div. I can print simple DOM nodes but soon as that - content_for line is reached it jumps. What am I missing?

Comment: The `form-group` div will be rendered wherever you have `= content_for :filter_exclude_words` (without a block) or a `yield ::filter_exclude_words`. Are you calling either of those somewhere?

Comment: Thanks @matt! Your response sent me in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843266/whats-the-right-syntax-to-use-rails-content-for-helper-in-a-haml-context